# A Matter of Flexibility: Index Variables vs. Constants

Tags: python

Consider the following hypothetical situation.

As part of an application you are developing in python, you must format a list of objects and assign each subsequent item to a provided keyword as a tuple. Here is the syntax:

```
entries = [keyword, [obj1, obj2, obj3, ...]]    # Original list of object entries

formatted = [(keyword, obj1), (keyword, obj2), (keyword, obj3), ...]
```

Here is the function that you propose (let me know if this can be more efficient):

```
def format(keyword, entries):
    return [(keyword, x) for x in entries[1][0]]
```

Here is the function applied:

```
foo = format(entries[0], entries[1])
```

**Flexibility Question**

Notice that the `entries` variable in the `format` function has static index integers `1` and `0`. Suppose that you anticipate that new terms may potentially be appended to the `entries` list. Would you normally use index variables instead of constants (expect incrementing constants for later items that will go into the list), and if so, would you use local or global indices? How do you account for this type of flexibility in your code?

Comment: Is there a reason you need `format` to be more efficient? That should be plenty fast enough for most use cases. And if it's not, you probably want to reorganize your code to use an iterator instead of a `list`, rather than just change the way you build the list.

Comment: If I find myself using `variables` for `indexes` for this `entries` in many places, I would consider making it a `namedtuple` or a `class`.

Comment: +1. I was just typing "If using a class doesn't seem appropriate, use a `namedtuple`, but @Satoru.Logic beat me to it. Using symbolic names for indices really isn't a pythonic solution, except when you're writing bindings for a C API that already has names for the indices (and even then, see, e.g., `os.stat`).

Comment: `format` does not need to be more efficient; I was just curious if you guys thought there could be a better method.

Comment: As another point: Maybe you want `format` to take a single parameter in the first place (and then split it internally), so you can just do `foo = format(entries)`. Or, alternatively, maybe `foo = format(*entries)` is the best way to do it. Without seeing more of your infrastructure, it's hard to be sure how clean that will end up looking.

Comment: `namedtuple` sounds like the way to go for multiple indices. I will have to experiment with this.

Comment: `sequence unpacking` may also be helpful for you in this case, since your `list` contains only two items, eg. `keyword, items = entries`

Comment: Note that `format` can be accomplished with `itertools.izip_longest` -- `list(itertools.izip_longest([],['foo','bar','baz'],fillvalue='keyword'))` -- much of time you don't even need a list, the iterable object works just fine :)

Comment: Depending on how it's used, as I implied, I might change format to either return a generator expression (or an `izip_longest`) instead of a `list`, or to be a generator function. (In 3.3, I'd `yield from` the expression. But without that, rewriting it as a generator might lower the realcode:boilerplate ratio for not much benefit.)

Comment: just a side note: I have found that using variables as indices (into dictionaries) can lead to difficulties when localizing your app to a foreign language  (especially when you use the keys as labels in the app)

Comment: @abarnert I like the `format(*entries)` technique. The goal of the `format` function is to rearrange the list and have the keyword binded to the subsequent objects as a tuple. So the `keyword` would be extracted from the original `entries` list.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what the question is here.  Could you try to clarify it?

Comment: For `format()` i think you meant `return [(keyword, x) for x in entries]`.

Comment: @martineau, I do not think so. The second index constant, `0`, provides me with the first item of the second term in the original list: all of the `entries` items.

Comment: @Biff: `entries` is both a global and a function argument, and in the function the argument will be used.

Comment: @martineau, you are right. I see now that indices aren't necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the function a keyword and a one-dimensional list. Why bother with the indices in the function definition? As written I get.

```
e = ['spam', ['aa','bb','cc','dd']]

def format(keyword, entries):
    return [(keyword, x) for x in entries[1][0]]

format(e[0], e[1])
[('spam', 'b')]
```

Depending on what the object is, you may get an index error. Indices aren't neccessary within the function.

```
def format(keyword, entries):
    return [(keyword, x) for x in entries]

format(e[0], e[1])
[('spam', 'aa'), ('spam', 'bb'), ('spam', 'cc'), ('spam', 'dd')]
```

This was already answered by martineau in the comments that I failed to read, so credit where credit is due. Sorry.

Comment: That certainly makes this more flexible knowing that indices aren't necessary. I would consider this the correct answer because you have made me realize that indices aren't necessary.

Comment: This just shows how to fix what I was indicating in my comments.

Comment: I am going to utilize the compacted `*args` technique with this as well.

Comment: Sorry, martineau, I'm new here and didn't see the comment. I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Biff & Jamie: No problem, things can get hectic when there's a lot of activity. Welcome to StackOverflow. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Putting together various solutions from the comments (Satoru.Logic and mgilson probably deserve more credit than me here):

```
def format(entries): # no need to split it in the caller
    # consider yield from instead of return in 3.3+
    return itertools.izip_longest([], entries[1][1][0], fill=entries[0])

foo = format(entries)
```

However, I'm not sure your original code was actually right.

When you call `format(entries[0], entries[1])`, that's going to be `format(keyword, [obj1, obj2, obj3, ...])`. Then, inside `format`, you're iterating over `entries[1][0]`, which means `obj2[0]`, ignoring all of the other entries. That doesn't seem correct. If `obj2` is actually the string `'obj2'`, for example, that's the letter `'o'`. So, `[(keyword, x) for x in entries[1][0]]` will just be `[('keyword', 'o')]`.

Comment: I have not used `itertools` yet - will look into that.

Comment: What's the advantage of `yield from` compared to `return` in python 3.3+?  I don't see a difference here (other than `return` will work with earlier versions.  Also, it's `zip_longest` in python3.

Comment: It's not an advantage of `yield from` over `return`, but an advantage of `yield from` over `yield`, if you want to make `format` be an actual generator function. In most cases, you really don't care either way, but if you do care, and you're on the fence, you may say "No, it's too much of a pain to loop and `yield`" with 2.7 or 3.2, but "Yeah, why not" with 3.3. I guess I should have explained that better in the answer.